# Assign a consecutive number to an array within an object

Tags: javascript, local-storage

I am creating an app in whichh the user inputs data from clients. This data will be stored at `localStorage`. Until here everything works fine. But I need to count the `length` of the object, then automaticaly assign a consecutive number to every client as it is created and saved. As `javascript` objects are numbered from 0, for example, the first client will be 0 on the `array` but in real life it is number 1. So, I need to iterate and get the last client as `js` ordered it, then add 1, then assign it to `clientn` to be stored on this client data.

**`Json`**

```
Clients:"[{
    "id":"qece2345-cd9d-4898-fd18-3ded710a8062",
    "hasPic":false,
    "picId":2,
    "picSrc":"",
    "picFile":[],
    "createdOn":"2023-03-30T14:22:22.899Z",
    "firstName":"JND PLUS MASTER",
    "job":"Destroza avernos",
    "clientn":""
    }]"
```

**`Js`**

```
function setClientNumber() {
    var clients = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("Clients")) || {};
    for (var m = 0; m < clients.length; m++) {
        clientNumber = clients.slice(-1)["0"].clientn;
        clients.push(client, clientNumber + '1');
        localStorage.setItem("Clients", JSON.stringify(clients));
}
```

**Expected result**

```
Clients:"[{
    "id":"qece2345-cd9d-4898-fd18-3ded710a8062",
    "hasPic":false,
    "picId":2,
    "picSrc":"",
    "picFile":[],
    "createdOn":"2023-03-30T14:22:22.899Z",
    "firstName":"JND PLUS MASTER",
    "job":"Destroza avernos",
    "clientn":"1"
    },{
    "id":"qece2345-cd9d-4898-fd18-3ded710a8062",
    "hasPic":false,
    "picId":2,
    "picSrc":"",
    "picFile":[],
    "createdOn":"2023-03-30T14:22:22.899Z",
    "firstName":"JND PLUS MASTER",
    "job":"Destroza avernos",
    "clientn":"2"
    },{
    "id":"qece2345-cd9d-4898-fd18-3ded710a8062",
    "hasPic":false,
    "picId":2,
    "picSrc":"",
    "picFile":[],
    "createdOn":"2023-03-30T14:22:22.899Z",
    "firstName":"JND PLUS MASTER",
    "job":"Destroza avernos",
    "clientn":"3"
    }]"
```

Note that the first client, `object 0`, has `"clientn":1`; `object 1`, has `"clientn":2`; `object 2`, has `"clientn":3`.

Comment: How are you determining uniqueness of the objects themselves, these objects all look the same, so what determines when you have a differing client to add a new clientn incremented value to? Or does this not matter you just want to get each object in the array of objects and add a `clientn` ***key/value*** where the value increments with each new object in the array?

Comment: I’m not sure what your question is.  It seems to be “write this code for me”,  but I could be mistaken.

Comment: The Json code given is just an example.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### In your `push` you are pushing two items for some reason

Try something simpler, like a `.map`

```
function runSetClientNumber() {
    const oldClients = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("Clients")) || {};
    const newClients = oldClients.map(
        (oldClient,zeroBasedIndex)=> ({
            ...oldClient,
            clientn: 1+zeroBasedIndex
        })
    );
    localStorage.setItem("Clients", JSON.stringify(newClients));
}
```

Comment: I have tried your solution but it fails when saving the new client data. `console.log(oldClients);` and `console.log(newClients);` shows the same existing clients with the correct value of `clientn`. Shouldn't `console.log(newClients);` show the client which is being created too? Any way, what I need is to save the new client data with the correct value of `clientn`. I am playing around with this to see if I can manage to do it correctly.

Comment: Ah, I assumed `setClientNumber` was just intended to _set the client number_. I now realise you were hoping it would add a client also. Presumably passed in via a parameter? Although your function doesn't have a parameter. I will update.

Comment: Actually, the old clients get the correct number, but in the new one, `clientn` is empty.

Comment: Strange. I am having difficulty what you mean by empty. `undefined`? A blank space? Not listed in the properties of the object? null? I can't think of a reason for any of them. I have added some explicit console.log's now. Can you try again and include the output in the question, so we can see where the problem is?

Comment: Empty means that in  `localstorage` the  `clientn` for the new client is empty. Like this: `{......."clientn":""}`. Now I realize that I should integrete your solution within the `function` which actually saves the client to `localstorage`

Comment: I hit the solution! It was your previous answer, I just called the `setClientNumber` function from within my own new client saving function, just after the new client is saved, then the `setClientNumber` do its job perfectly. I will update de answer for further references.